# emit is not working when user click in angular 8 (dataservice)

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on Parent to child to sub child output, the sub child output will display in Modal popup.

From Parent to child(First) working perfectly fine. The data will be the same as below so when the user click Department list from the first child the data has to populate in modal window

this is what my try **modalpopup.ts**

```
      export class ModalPopupTrialTypeComponent implements OnInit {
      public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TrialDetails>([]);
      private unsubscribe: Subscription[] = [];
      public columnsToDisplay: string[] = [ 'firstName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'Age', 'Designation', 'Salary'];
      @Input() trailData:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

      constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
         ngOnInit() {

          }
          ngOnDestroy() {
            this.unsubscribe.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());
          }    
      }
```

Here is what my Html

```
<table class="nested-table" mat-table [dataSource]="trailData" multiTemplateDataRows matSort>
<ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.firstName}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Address">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Address </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Address}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Age">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Age </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Age}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Designation">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Designation </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Designation}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="Salary">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Salary </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Salary}}
     </td>
 </ng-container>
 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay" style="display: none;" ></tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="example-element-row"
     [class.example-expanded-row]="isExpandedElement === element"
     (click)="isExpandedElement = isExpandedElement === element ? null : element">
 </tr>
 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expanedDetail']" class="example-detail-row">
 </tr>
```

Please let me know what I am doing here.

Answer (score 1):

This link can give you a good understanding of component interactions:

```
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component does not emit because [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) it is used with the `@Input` directive instead `@Output`.

You should have an `@Input` decorator for populate the table and an `@Output` for emit data from child to parent.

For instance:

```
@Input() trailData: TrialDetails;
@Output() emitToParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Comment: thank you for the post so i have to put this in the child component

Comment: @Input() trailData: TrialDetails;
  @Output() emitToParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
     ngOnInit() {

      }
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribe.forEach(sb => sb.unsubscribe());
      }
    
  }

Here is my update is this correct

Comment: but still no data was displaying

Comment: try console the `trailData` in `ngOnInit`

Comment: still showing empty page bit confusing when i have component tag name it was working but when i use the click method i am not getting any data

Comment: Can you share and stackblitz with the example.

Comment: when i tried to console trialData was showing undefined

Comment: @Mahadevan I need to see your code, to know how your are injecting data from parent to child.